# Splitting a table cell between right and left alignment with colored rows

Tags: tables, colortbl, glue

I'm trying to make a table that's essentially a feature matrix. Entries are grouped, and each group is a set of completions to a sentence. Because of space constraints, I'm trying to keep the start of the sentence and the first completion on the same line, like so:

[image: Working without row colors]

However, I'd like to add row colors to better differentiate the groups. I've achieved the effect of pushing the text in each group header to the sides by adding `\hskip`s in between the two pieces...but then, as documented in the `colortbl` comments, the color falls short of reaching the end of the cell:

[image: Not working with colored rows]

Is there a way to achieve this combination of effects without that ugly gap in coloration, either by tweaking colortbl-related code or by using a different mechanism to split the group headers? (Or perhaps a different design solution altogether...)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\rowgrpheader}[2]{\textbf{#1\ldots} \hskip 5pt plus 1filll \ldots #2}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rcc}
  \toprule
  & \textbf{Broke a chain} & \textbf{Freed a human soul} \\ \midrule
  \rowcolor[gray]{.85} \rowgrpheader{Loyalty to}{a petrified opinion} & \xmark & \xmark \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{.85} \ldots principled open-mindedness & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \rowgrpheader{Telling other people to}{shut up} & \xmark & \xmark \\
  \ldots be their best selves & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way with `tabularx` (and `makecell`, for a better look):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, makecell, bigstrut}
\usepackage{pifont}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\newcommand{\rowgrpheader}[2]{\textbf{#1\ldots} \hskip 5pt plus 1filll \ldots #2}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\raggedleft}Xcc}
  \toprule
  & \thead{Broke a chain} & \thead{Freed a\\ human soul} \\
  \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro!70} \rowgrpheader{Loyalty to}{a petrified opinion} & \xmark & \xmark\bigstrut[t] \\
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro!70} \ldots principled open-mindedness & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \rowgrpheader{Telling other people to}{shut up} & \xmark & \xmark \\
  \ldots be their best selves & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the white gap by simply using a fixed width column type like `p` or `m` for the first column.

As the table exceeds the textwidth, I have included `tabularx` and adjusted the widths of the second and third column.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{colortbl,booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XC{2cm}C{2.5cm}}
  \toprule
  & \textbf{Broke a chain} & \textbf{Freed a human soul} \\ \midrule
 \rowcolor[gray]{.85} \textbf{Loyalty to \ldots} \hfill  \ldots a petrified solution & \xmark & \xmark \\
 \rowcolor[gray]{.85}  \raggedleft \ldots principled open-mindedness & \cmark & \cmark \\
 \textbf{Telling other people to \ldots} \hfill \ldots shut up  & \xmark & \xmark \\
 \raggedleft \ldots be their best selves & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

- I have loaded `nicematrix` (and unloaded `colortbl`).
- I have replaced `{tabular}` with `{NiceTabular}` with the key `colortbl-like`.

The output is directly the expected output (because, in `nicematrix`, the color instructions are treated with PGF/Tikz).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\rowgrpheader}[2]{\textbf{#1\ldots} \hskip 5pt plus 1filll \ldots #2}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{rcc}[colortbl-like]
  \toprule
  & \textbf{Broke a chain} & \textbf{Freed a human soul} \\ \midrule
  \rowcolor[gray]{.85} \rowgrpheader{Loyalty to}{a petrified opinion} & \xmark & \xmark \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{.85} \ldots principled open-mindedness & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \rowgrpheader{Telling other people to}{shut up} & \xmark & \xmark \\
  \ldots be their best selves & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]